# RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists) when I append hdf5 file?

Tags: python-3.x, file, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to append the hdf5 dataset to the previous hdf5 dataset
following error occured

> h5o.link(obj.id, self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl, lapl=self._lapl)   File
>   "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
>   File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper 
>   File "h5py/h5o.pyx", line 202, in h5py.h5o.link RuntimeError: Unable
>   to create link (name already exists)

```
 sal_maps = np.array([], dtype=np.float32).reshape((0,) + img_size)
        probs = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
        preds = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
        for idx, (img, target) in enumerate(dataloader):

    # TODO problem1 idx problem
            sal_maps_b, probs_b, preds_b = self.generate_image(img, idx)
            sal_maps_b = np.transpose(sal_maps_b, axes=(3,0, 1, 2))

            sal_maps = np.vstack([sal_maps,sal_maps_b])
            probs = np.append(probs, probs_b)
            preds = np.append(preds,preds_b)
            #if idx ==2: break
            if idx % 100 == 0:
                print("idx->{} sal_maps->{}, probs->{} , preds->{}".format(idx,sal_maps.shape,probs.shape,preds.shape))

        # TODO indent change

                print("result->{}".format(sal_maps.size))
                with h5py.File(self.datapath, 'a') as hf:
                    hf.create_dataset('saliencys', data=sal_maps)
                    hf.create_dataset('probs', data=probs)
                    hf.create_dataset('preds', data=preds)
                    hf.close()
                sal_maps = np.array([], dtype=np.float32).reshape((0,) + img_size)
                probs = np.array([], dtype=np.float32)
                preds = np.array([], dtype=np.uint8)
                print('Save_saliency_maps::',idx)
```

Comment: You can't use `create_dataset` if a dataset with that name already exists in the file and group.

Comment: then If I want to append another hf.create_dataset('saliencys', data=sal_maps) to the file how should I do that??

Comment: You can use `require_dataset`. If will use an existing dataset, or create the dataset if it doesn't exist. HOWEVER, you have to take care not to overwrite data in an existing dataset. Be sure you add new data to the end.