# TensorFlow 2.x: Cannot save trained model in h5 format (OSError: Unable to create link (name already exists))

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, h5py

My model uses pre-processed data to predict if a customer is a private or non-private customer. The pre-processing-step is using steps like feature_column.bucketized_column(…), feature_column.embedding_column(…) and so on.
After the training, I am trying to save the model but I get the following error:

> File "h5py_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
> File "h5py_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
> File "h5py\h5o.pyx", line 202, in h5py.h5o.link
> OSError: Unable to create link (name already exists)

I have tried the following to solve my problem:

- I tried to exclude the optimizer as mentioned here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27688.
- I tried different versions of TensorFlow like 2.2 and 2.3.
- I tried to reinstall h5py like mentioned here: [RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists) when I append hdf5 file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59187054/runtimeerror-unable-to-create-link-name-already-exists-when-i-append-hdf5-fil).

Everything without success!

Here is the relevant code of the Model:

```py
(feature_columns, train_ds, val_ds, test_ds) = preprocessing.getPreProcessedDatasets(args.data, args.zip, args.batchSize)

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns, trainable=False)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        feature_layer,
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    ])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        metrics=['accuracy'])

paramString = "Arg-e{}-b{}-z{}".format(args.epoch, args.batchSize, bucketSizeGEO)

...

model.fit(train_ds,
              validation_data=val_ds,
              epochs=args.epoch,
              callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])


model.summary()

loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(test_ds)
print("Accuracy", accuracy)

paramString = paramString + "-a{:.4f}".format(accuracy)

outputName = "logReg" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + paramStrin

if args.saveModel:
       filepath = "./saved_models/" + outputName + ".h5"
       model.save(filepath, save_format='h5')
```

Called function in preprocessing Modul:

```py
def getPreProcessedDatasets(filepath, zippath, batch_size, bucketSizeGEO):
    print("start preprocessing...")

    path = filepath
    data = pd.read_csv(path, dtype={
    "NAME1": np.str_, 
    "NAME2": np.str_, 
    "EMAIL1": np.str_, 
    "ZIP": np.str_, 
    "STREET": np.str_, 
    "LONGITUDE":np.floating, 
    "LATITUDE": np.floating, 
    "RECEIVERTYPE": np.int64}) 

    feature_columns = []

    data = data.fillna("NaN")

    data = __preProcessName(data)
    data = __preProcessStreet(data)
    
    train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
    train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    train_ds = __df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
    val_ds = __df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
    test_ds = __df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)


    __buildFeatureColums(feature_columns, data, zippath, bucketSizeGEO, True)

    print("preprocessing completed")

    return (feature_columns, train_ds, val_ds, test_ds)
```

Calling the different preprocessing functions of the features:

```py
def __buildFeatureColums(feature_columns, data, zippath, bucketSizeGEO, addCrossedFeatures):
    
    feature_columns.append(__getFutureColumnLon(bucketSizeGEO))
    feature_columns.append(__getFutureColumnLat(bucketSizeGEO))
    
    (namew1_one_hot, namew2_one_hot) = __getFutureColumnsName(__getNumberOfWords(data, 'NAME1PRO'))
    feature_columns.append(namew1_one_hot)
    feature_columns.append(namew2_one_hot)
    
    feature_columns.append(__getFutureColumnStreet(__getNumberOfWords(data, 'STREETPRO')))
    
    feature_columns.append(__getFutureColumnZIP(2223, zippath))
    
    if addCrossedFeatures:
        feature_columns.append(__getFutureColumnCrossedNames(100))
        feature_columns.append(__getFutureColumnCrossedZIPStreet(100, 2223, zippath))
```

Function reletated to embeddings:

```py
def __getFutureColumnsName(name_num_words):
    vocabulary_list = np.arange(0, name_num_words + 1, 1).tolist()

    namew1_voc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        key='NAME1W1', vocabulary_list=vocabulary_list, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64)
    namew2_voc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        key='NAME1W2', vocabulary_list=vocabulary_list, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64)

    dim = __getNumberOfDimensions(name_num_words)

    namew1_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(namew1_voc, dimension=dim)
    namew2_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(namew2_voc, dimension=dim)

    return (namew1_embedding, namew2_embedding)
```

```py
def __getFutureColumnStreet(street_num_words):
    vocabulary_list = np.arange(0, street_num_words + 1, 1).tolist()

    street_voc = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
        key='STREETW', vocabulary_list=vocabulary_list, dtype=tf.dtypes.int64)

    dim = __getNumberOfDimensions(street_num_words)

    street_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(street_voc, dimension=dim)

    return street_embedding
```

```py
def __getFutureColumnZIP(zip_num_words, zippath):
    zip_voc = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file(
    key='ZIP', vocabulary_file=zippath, vocabulary_size=zip_num_words,
    default_value=0)

    dim = __getNumberOfDimensions(zip_num_words)

    zip_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(zip_voc, dimension=dim)

    return zip_embedding
```

Comment: The cause of the error is some duplicate variable names in the model. There can be a variety of reasons. First we need to know which variables have duplicate names. Please run this before saving and report the results here: `for i, w in enumerate(model.weights): print(i, w.name)`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Here is the result:
_0 sequential/dense_features/embedding_weights:0_
_1 sequential/dense_features/embedding_weights:0_
_2 sequential/dense_features/embedding_weights:0_
_3 sequential/dense_features/embedding_weights:0_
_4 sequential/dense/kernel:0_
_5 sequential/dense/bias:0_

Comment: The `embedding_weights` name are duplicate. So the cause is somewhere in your preprocessing pipeline. Could you upload your preprocessing code?

Comment: I have edited the original question, so that you can see the relevant preprocessing steps.

Comment: Maybe you can try passing explicit name to the keras feature layer `feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns, trainable=False, name=['emb1','emb2', 'emb3', 'emb4'])`. I'm not so sure, the updated code seems still missing something.

Comment: When building each `feature_column`, if you pass the different `key`, they should have different `name` and will work OK. Something does not add up here. The updated codes also do not consistently link to each other. Maybe you ran some other modifications of the codes.

Comment: Answer to your previous comment: Unfortunately, it’s not possible to pass a list of names: _ TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str_. Furthermore, it seems that the name parameter is related to the layer and not to the weights:
_0 sequential/emb1/embedding_weights:0_
_1 sequential/emb1/embedding_weights:0_
_2 sequential/emb1/embedding_weights:0_
_3 sequential/emb1/embedding_weights:0_
_4 sequential/dense/kernel:0_
_5 sequential/dense/bias:0_

Comment: Every feature_column should have key, otherwise it wouldn't be possible to find the corresponding column of the input data. The edited code should be consistent, I didn't do any modification. Maybe the problem is related to _ckpt_to_load_from_ and _tensor_name_in_ckpt_ of _embedding_column_. I will try to change something here, maybe it will help. But your hint seems to be plausible, thanks for that!

Comment: As supposed by you, the problem was the names of weights of the embedding columns. After deleting two of the three embeddings, so that there is only one variable with the name _embedding_weights_, I was able to save the model in the h5 format. I couldn’t find any way to rename the variables. But as mentioned here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43011 the problem is fixed in TF-nigthly!
Could you write a summary of our findings as an answer, so I can reward you with the bounty? Thank you so much!

Comment: OK, good to hear problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error `OSError: Unable to create link (name already exists)` when saving model in h5 format is caused by some duplicate variable names. Checking by `for i, w in enumerate(model.weights): print(i, w.name)` showed that they are the embedding_weights names.

Normally, when building `feature_column`, the distinct `key` passed into each feature column will be used to build distinct variable `name`. This worked correctly in TF 2.1 but broke in TF 2.2 and 2.3, and supposedly [fixed in TF 2.4 nigthly](http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43011).

Comment: Sorry for bother you but do you maybe also have an answer to my following related question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/63810835/11986067

Comment: For those who don't want to switch to nightly, i solved it using `for i in range(len(model.layers)): model.layer[i]._handle_name = model.layer[i]._name + "_" + str(i)` . I did it in tf2.3 and don't suggest it because it manipulates an underscored variable (that's why not posting as an answer)

Answer (score 4):

My workaround for TF 2.3 is based on @SajanGohil's comment, but my issue was with *weight* names (not *layer* names):

```
for i in range(len(model.weights)):
    model.weights[i]._handle_name = model.weights[i].name + "_" + str(i)
```

The same caveats apply: this approach manipulates TF internals and thus is not future-proof.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Tensorflow 2.3.1

Answer (score -1):

I found out that this situation also occurs when I load a model from a modelcheckpoint, model.compile it with same optimizer, metrics and loss function, and train it.
But if I avoid compiling it again with same parameters, this error message would not show up again.