# ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists) when using ModelCheckpoint to save my model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, transformer-model

I am trying to run the Keras Offical Code Example "Image classification with Swin Transformers". The code works fine at first, but after I added a ModelCheckpoint to save the hdf5 model in the callbacks arguement of the model.fit method{i.e. model.fit(..., callbacks=[ModelCheckpoint(...)], ..., )}, I received the following error [ ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists) ]. What does "name" refer to here? How should I solve this problem?

I ran the code on my local device (windows10, tensorflow2.8.0) and Google Colab(tensorflow2.8.2) and both get the above error.

The full code example can be found here [https://keras.io/examples/vision/swin_transformers/] ,The only difference between my code and Code Example is that I added a line of code for ModelCheckpoint. The location of the added code and the error message are shown below.

**Code fragment**:

```
model = keras.Model(input, output)
model.compile(
    loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(label_smoothing=label_smoothing),
    optimizer=tfa.optimizers.AdamW(
        learning_rate=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay
    ),
    metrics=[
        keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name="accuracy"),
        keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(5, name="top-5-accuracy"),
    ],
)

history = model.fit(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    epochs=num_epochs,
    validation_split=validation_split,
    #  I added one line of code
    callbacks = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('lowest_loss.hdf5', monitor='loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
)
```

**This is the error I got**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-c96b13609516> in <module>()
     18     validation_split=validation_split,
     19     #  I added one line of code
---> 20     callbacks = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('lowest_loss.hdf5', monitor='loss', verbose=0, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
     21 )

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py in create_dataset(self, name, shape, dtype, data, **kwds)
    146                     group = self.require_group(parent_path)
    147 
--> 148             dsid = dataset.make_new_dset(group, shape, dtype, data, name, **kwds)
    149             dset = dataset.Dataset(dsid)
    150             return dset

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py in make_new_dset(parent, shape, dtype, data, name, chunks, compression, shuffle, fletcher32, maxshape, compression_opts, fillvalue, scaleoffset, track_times, external, track_order, dcpl, allow_unknown_filter)
    135 
    136 
--> 137     dset_id = h5d.create(parent.id, name, tid, sid, dcpl=dcpl)
    138 
    139     if (data is not None) and (not isinstance(data, Empty)):

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5d.pyx in h5py.h5d.create()

ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64118599/getting-the-runtimeerror-unable-to-create-link-name-already-exists-with-a-mul)

Comment: If the model file already exists, delete it, since it needs to be created from scratch.

Comment: @AyanamiRei, please check this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63785845/14290697), it might help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this error occurs when the layer names are duplicates across the namespaces of the pre-trained model and your downstream-task network. It may be useful to choose a unique name to call every layer of your downstream task network. Add a `name='some_unique_name'` to all the layers you create to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this , it worked for me

```
for i in range(len(model.weights)):
    model.weights[i]._handle_name = model.weights[i].name + "_" + str(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using TensorFlow version 2.0 or above, you can try to change the ".hdf5" files to ".tf".   Having met the same problem, I changed file extensions as follows:

```py
save_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "save_models")
filepath = "cnn_cnn_weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.4f}--0fold.tf"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(save_dir, filepath),
                             monitor="val_loss", verbose=1, save_best_only=False, mode='min')
```

Comment: Unlike the other answers, changing the file extension (h5 or hbf5 to tf) fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but this is a code I created to save checkpoints and load the latest checkpoint based on the saved .h5 file's name to continue training a Keras model and avoid repeating epochs. I hope it helps you because I had the same error as yours, "ValueError: Unable to create dataset (name already exists)."

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow.keras as keras
import os
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

# Prepare the dataset
train_ds = (
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataset)
    .batch(16)
    .cache()
    .prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
)

# Define the number of epochs for demonstration
num_epochs = 3

# Directory to save the checkpoints
checkpoint_dir = "checkpoints/"

# Callback to save checkpoints per epoch
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "model_{epoch:02d}.h5"),
    save_freq="epoch",
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_best_only=False,
    verbose=1
)

# Check if there are existing checkpoints to resume from the last one
checkpoint_files = [file for file in os.listdir(checkpoint_dir) if file.endswith('.h5')]
if checkpoint_files:
    latest_checkpoint = max(checkpoint_files)
    gpt2_lm.load_weights(os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, latest_checkpoint))

    # Get the epoch number from the checkpoint file name
    num_epoch_resume = int(latest_checkpoint.split("_")[1].split(".")[0])
    
    # Train the model
    history = gpt2_lm.fit(train_ds, initial_epoch=num_epoch_resume, epochs=num_epochs, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
    print("hello")
else:
    # No existing checkpoints, train the model from scratch
    history = gpt2_lm.fit(train_ds, epochs=num_epochs, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue. However, my issue was when trying to save the whole model instead of the weights.

For this case, maybe you can clear the keras session before compiling the model.

Add this line of code before `model.compile`

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```